# Google Maps POI

Tags: google, maps

Estou precisando montar um maps do google no meu projeto (inserir um mapa) e mostrar os pontos de interesse  proximo. Pontos de interesse, seria tudo que tem perto, padaria, bar, postos e etc.
Existe como? Como faço? Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Você vai criar o projeto para Android, Web?

Answer (score 0):

O Google disponibiliza um manual para a API do Google Maps, você pode encontrar no seguinte link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/

Faltou mencionar se o projeto vai ser desenvolvido para Android, Web (JavaScript), iOS ou HTTP, porém neste site está tudo o que você precisa. Não é difícil de utilizar, nada que a lógica, conhecimento na linguagem que irá utilizar e da API não resolvam.

Comment: Giancarlo, é web em JS. Já procurei anteriormente na documentação do mãos, porem não tem nada referente ao consumo de poi.